# Print Previous Image Name

Tags: android

I have a `Button` a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. When I click button a rondom image will appear and TextView show image name. But I don't need it. TextView must show previous image name. How can I do it?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        TypedArray ar = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.logolar);
        int len = ar.length();
        int[] resIds = new int[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            resIds[i] = ar.getResourceId(i, 0);
        ar.recycle();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(resIds.length) + 1;
        try {
            int resID = resIds[rndInt];
            ImageView logolar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logolar);
            logolar.setImageResource(resID);
            String lastImageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resID); //String lastImageName = getResources().getResourceName(resID); // bu da kullanilabilir
            TextView logoismi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logoismi);
            logoismi.setText(lastImageName);
            clickeddata.add(logoismi.getText().toString()); //bir onceki logo verilerini depolama ozelligi
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Consider thread function in delay, or delayed start in thread. Hope that is what you intended. Cant understand your wants clearly.

Comment: I want to, when I click button next image will appear the same time print previous image drawable name in textView...

Comment: Huh man please help?

Comment: I cannot understand your english. Make it short, or make it eligible by numbering the steps.